# Clojure project layout and relative imports

Tags: clojure

I'm having a hard time starting out on my first clojure project. I have found a ton of tutorials and answers to questions, but none of the seems to answer my problem.

I have created a blank project using Leiningen. This example explains my problem:

`project.clj:`

```
(defproject clojurenet "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [ [org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]
                  [net.mikera/core.matrix "0.34.0"]
                  [org.clojure/math.numeric-tower "0.0.1"]]
  :main ^:skip-aot clojurenet.core
  :target-path "target/%s"
  :profiles {:uberjar {:aot :all}})
```

`src/clojurenet/core.clj:`

```
(ns clojurenet.core)
  (:require clojurenet.hello)
  (:gen-class))

(defn -main
  [& args]
  (clojurenet.hello/helloworld)
```

`src/clojurenet/hello.clj:`

```
(ns clojurenet.hello)

(defn helloworld []
    (println "Hello World!"))
```

When I run `lein run` I get the error message `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: clojurenet.hello, compiling:(clojurenet/core.clj:2:3)`. How am I supposed to do this?

I would also rather use `:refer :all` syntax in the core file, but i belive this example should be the simplest.

I'm sure there is a stupid simple solution to this, but my research has not been successful.

Additionally, do you have som good tutorials for building you first project? I find that some tutorials are outdated, and most of the only describes how to use the REPL.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried `lein clean`?

Comment: Also your parantheses are unbalanced after `clojurenet.core`

Comment: Thank you! Tah was the simple stupid solution I was looking for, the parenthesis

Comment: I recommend to use a balancer like paredit to prevent this from happening...

Comment: I currently a user of Sublime Text, and not Emacs. I will look for some similar option for Sublime :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have unbalanced parantheses in `clojurenet.core`

```
(ns clojurenet.core) ;; <- remove ) to fix
  (:require clojurenet.hello)
  (:gen-class))
```

I recommend using a balancing editing mode like [ParEdit](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ParEdit). You may want to try out [this](https://github.com/odyssomay/paredit) implementation if you are using Sublime.